# Shouldn't “some of the phenomenon” be plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, suffixes, greek, inflectional-morphology

The paragraph:

> Our team conducts fundamental research in Philosophy, trying to push
>   the boundaries of what is possible with new techniques, and also trying
>   to understand and formalize *some of the* **phenomenon** observed in
>   practice.
>   [Source](https://ai.google/research/people/SylvainGelly)

My Greek instinct read *phenomena* instead of phenomenon... Am I correct? Or, in English it's OK to use it like this?

Comment: Yes you are, and no it's not.

Comment: . . . unless it is a single phenomenon—and *some* is referring to just a part of it. Then the singular would be fine. But, semantically, I don't see how that makes sense.

Comment: @JasonBassford that's why I included the whole paragraph..To cross check that I am not misunderstanding the semantics here...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> …*some of the **phenomenon***…

Consider that usage as a typo, it's like *criteria* vs *criterion*, many use the former thinking it is an uncountable noun while other speakers add an "s", i.e. [criterias](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/criterias), to make it plural.

The study of Greek and Latin does not enjoy the same prestige as it used to in the past, so we shall hear the following with increasing frequency: [*phenomenons*](https://www.heart.co.uk/lifestyle/2018-dates-best-natural-wonders/) and [*datas*](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2014/04/29/data-media-two-tricky-latin-plurals-handle/) and *[agendas](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/agenda)* in the future.

> The OED‘s evidence shows that the plurals *datas* (first recorded in 1645) and *medias* (appearing in 1927) have a long history and crop up in varied sources, from scientific and academic journals to *The Times*.
>
> *Oxford Dictionaries Blog*

I found this 2011 article in the *[Daily Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/8533792/Weird-weather-the-top-ten-strangest-phenomenons.html)*, an exemplary hodgepodge, but at least both forms are recognizable as being plural.

> ### Weird weather: the top ten strangest phenomenons
>
> Scientists now believe that tiny bugs in the earth's atmosphere can cause storm clouds to form. Here is a list of 10 other amazing weather **phenomena**